# input() problem jupyter notebook and other website

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a website called *NOWCODER*, similar to the *Leetcode* but a Chinese version.

One of the question is **asking for user to input some text(multiple lines) and determine whether the texts that enter are qualified as an appropriate password.**

What bothers me is the `input()`

so I write my code on Jupyter notebook (python 3) as:

```
# 1st Code

s = [] # get all the input text
while True:
    try:
        lines = input()
        if lines:
            s.append(lines)
        else:
            break
```

the code works fine in jupyter nootbook but when i copied it to the nowcoder website it doesn't work, it said "no input and output data"

so i modified the code to the following:

```
# 2nd Code

s = []
while True:
    try:
        s.append(input())
    except:
        break
```

and it works

The problem is now I tried to execute the 2nd Code in the *Jupyter* notebook, the while loop never ends and keeps asking for input. I don't know how to fix it or where is the problem.

Also i try `re.stdin.readline()` and it doenst work on jupyter nootbook, so I want to know if there is some way to make it executable on both the *NOWCODER* website as well as on the *Jupyter* notebook

Comment: The first code is invalid because the `try` doesn't have an `except` or `finally`. It must be masking an exception if you don't see an error. Otherwise, there's no different between the code. The behavior should be identical.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thank you! I modified the 1st Code and it works great on NOWCODER but the 2nd Code just doesnt work well on jupyter notebook, it wont break the loop, any idea?

Comment: You don't have any condition that break the loop, you just keep adding empty string to the `s` list.

Comment: @Amiram so is there a way to break the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code is fine, you just need to send an end-of-file signal (EOF), which you can do on Unix/Linux with Ctrl+D and on Windows with Ctrl+Z. Python receives this as an `EOFError`, which your `except` clause will catch and break the loop. However, a [bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/4518341). You should at least change it to `except Exception`.

That said, you could simplify massively by using [`fileinput.input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) to take input.

```
import fileinput
s = [s.rstrip('\n') for s in fileinput.input()]
```